# Camera rotation with arrow keys - centered on object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm having a strange bug with my code. The camera is centered on the player (first-person), who can move around with WASD. The camera is rotated independently with his head with UPDOWNLEFTRIGHT. I want the head to only move up, down, left, right - no tilting or going upside-down. At the start it does this, but soon the camera starts to get a mind of its own. EDIT: I believe this is because, when i look down/up the axis changes and then when left/right is pressed, the view is changed according to this new axis.

Code for camera to follow player:

```
public class FollowPlayer : MonoBehaviour {

    public Transform player;
    public Vector3 offset;
    private int cameraRotSpeed = 100;

    void Update () {
        transform.position = player.position + offset;

         Vector3 v3 = new Vector3(Input.GetAxis("Vertical"), Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"), 0.0f);
         transform.Rotate(v3 * cameraRotSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

Code for player movement:

```
public class movement : MonoBehaviour {
   public Rigidbody rb;

    public float yForce = 300f; //left/right 
    public float xForce = 600f; //forward/back
    public int rotateSpeed = 25;

    private bool wPressed;
    private bool aPressed;
    private bool sPressed;
    private bool dPressed;

    void Start () {
        wPressed = aPressed = sPressed = dPressed = false;
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKey("w"))
        {
            wPressed = true;
        }

        if (Input.GetKey("a"))
        {
            aPressed = true;
        }

        if (Input.GetKey("s"))
        {
            sPressed = true;
        }

        if (Input.GetKey("d"))
        {
            dPressed = true;
        }
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void FixedUpdate () {
        //Time.deltaTime evens out the speed to account for frame rate
        if (Input.GetKey("w"))
        {
            rb.AddRelativeForce(-xForce * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0);

            wPressed = false;
        }
        if (Input.GetKey("a"))
        {
            rb.AddRelativeForce(0, 0, -yForce * Time.deltaTime);

            transform.Rotate(-Vector3.up * rotateSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
            aPressed = false;
        }
        if (Input.GetKey("s"))
        {
            rb.AddRelativeForce(xForce * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0);


            sPressed = false;
        }
        if (Input.GetKey("d"))
        {
            rb.AddRelativeForce(0, 0, yForce * Time.deltaTime);

            transform.Rotate(Vector3.up * rotateSpeed * Time.deltaTime);

            dPressed = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Normally the camera starts to tilt when to arrow keys are pressed at the same time, but can also happen when only one is pressed. Anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have actually only figured out how to do this today - a little delayed. Thank you to @avariant, for inspiring the solution. 
The coordinate system was actually set to Space.World by default for some reason. I simply needed to use Space.Self instead.
So to alter the example given by Avariant:

```
transform.Rotate(Vector3.up * rotateSpeed * Time.deltaTime, Space.Self);
```

Answer (score 0):

By default, `transform.Rotate` occurs in "self space", the local coordinate system relative to what the transform is looking at (forward, back, left and right).  You are right that your view is getting messed up because your operations on are on the local coordinate system.

`transform.Rotate` has an option parameter to specify the coordinate system to use.  You want the global or world coordinate system, like this:

```
transform.Rotate(Vector3.up * rotateSpeed * Time.deltaTime, Space.World);
```

You can find more in the Unity Docs here: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.Rotate.html

Comment: This looked like an easy solution, but it hasn't worked :/ My MainCamera has a script FollowPlayer which I showed above. Perhaps my camera is permanently linked to player and therefore is already world view - space.world has not made a difference?

Comment: You have rotate in both scripts, in a few different places.  Did you add the flag in all the locations?